# Checkbox doesn't work when I use several renderUi on Shiny

Tags: checkbox, shiny

I used a checkbox in my Shiny app that didn't work (couldn't update).

I tried to reach the root of the problem, and found that it appeared when I wrote the second "renderUi" function in my code (output$secondSelectionVarIllu, the 2nd function in the server) : when I delete it, the checkbox works.

Does anyone know why ?

What is the problem in my code ?

PS : I use renderUi because if I write the sliderInput in the ui, I don't achieve to include "input$choix_var" in the parameters. If there is another solution for that, it could also delete the problem, even if I'd like to understand this matter of checkbox !

PS2 : it isn't a problem of data, the only thing that doesn't work is the TRUE/FALSE option of the checkbox

Thank you very much !

```
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(inputId = "choix_var",label="Variables utilisées pour la construction des axes :",
                  choices=as.list(noms_var),multiple=T),

      uiOutput("secondSelectionNbAxes"),
      uiOutput("secondSelectionVarIllu"),

      checkboxInput(inputId = "aff_histo_vp","Affichage de l'histogramme des valeurs propres",TRUE)
   ),

    mainPanel(
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.aff_histo_vp",
             plotOutput("histo_vp")            
        )
    )
  )
)


# Define server ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$secondSelectionNbAxes <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "nb_axes",label="Choix du nombre de composantes principales :",
                min=2,max=length(input$choix_var),value=2,step=1)
  })

  output$secondSelectionVarIllu <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(condition="length(input$choix_var) < nb_var",
                     selectInput(inputId = "choix_var_illu",label="Variables illustratives :",
                                 choices=names(data_acp_cr)[which(!names(data_acp_cr) %in% names(data_acp_cr[,which(names(data_acp_cr) %in% input$choix_var)]))],multiple=T))
  }) 

  output$histo_vp <- renderPlot({
     acp <- dudi.pca(data_acp_cr[,which(names(data_acp_cr) %in% input$choix_var)],scannf = F,nf=input$nb_axes) 
    fviz_eig(acp,main="Histogramme des valeurs propres") 
  })
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with the `condition="length(input$choix_var) < nb_var"` inside the `conditionalPanel` within `renderUI` of `secondSelectionVarIllu `

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But do you know why ? (indeed it works when I delete the line with the conditionalPanel, is it because we can't use a conditionalPanel in a renderUI ?)

Comment: Actually, the condition you give should be in JavaScript format while you have it in R format. I'm not sure but I guess that is what is causing the problem. I'm actually commenting from my phone otherwise I could've checked and told you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, indeed, I'm not familiar with JavaScript, I use Shiny from my skills on R. I can wait for your answer, thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Can't seem to find the variable `nb_var`. Its just there in the `condition` for `conditionalPanel`, no where other than that. What exactly does that variable for?

Comment: Yes indeed. It is a maximum for length(input$choix_var), its value is 84. I didn't copy here the lines where it is defined. However it isn't the matter, the problem remains when I change it by 84.

Comment: (just to explain the context : it's an app to visualize PCA results. 

l.5-6 in "selectInput(inputId = "choix_var",...)", I choose the variables that are used to build the principal components.

l.26-27 in "selectInput(inputId = "choix_var_illu",...)", I choose additional variables. But only if the variables haven't all been selected in "choix_var", that means only if length(input$choix_var) < nb_var. 
(nb_var is the total number of variables in the dataset)

But I thought it wasn't necessary to understand that to solve the problem.

Comment: You should try `condition="input.choix_var.length < 84"` instead as the condition should be in javascript format.

Comment: Ok, it works, thank you very much !! :)
I didn't know that we could use another way of writing than R language on Shiny !

Comment: And if it is not too much to ask you : I keep the same problem for another renderUI, with "condition="input.nb_axes > 2". Do you see also a problem of javascript format here ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. `nb_axes` is `sliderInput` right?

Comment: Yes ! I've juste added : 
output$secondSelectionAxes <- renderUI({
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.nb_axes > 2",
                     selectInput(inputId = "choix_axe1",label="1er axe",
                                 choices=1:input$nb_axes,selected=1,multiple=F),
                     selectInput(inputId = "choix_axe2",label="2e axe",
                                 choices=1:input$nb_axes,selected=2,multiple=F))
  })
 in the server, and also uiOutput("secondSelectionAxes") in the ui. I've got the same problem again ^^

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't perhaps easy to read. To sum up I simply use 2 "selectInput" depending on the condition "input.nb_axes > 2". I tried again after deleting one of the two selectInput, deleting the condition, and changing "input$nb_axes" in the parameters by an integer. But it still doesn't work...